# I am trying to split the function compute() into 2 separate ones

Tags: python, function

I want the function compute() to consist of 2 functions. 1 function including part 1 and the second one part 2. Keep in mind that compute() gets called up in another function aswell.

```
import hashlib
import requests
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()

def error():
    error_message = Label(root, text="\n\nThis is not a valid password")
    error_message.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


def compute(password):
### part 1 of the function
    encoded_str = password.encode()
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(encoded_str)
    hashed = hash_obj.hexdigest().upper()
    beginning = hashed[:5]
    ending = hashed[5:].strip()
    response = requests.get("https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/" + beginning)
    output = response.text
    listing = output.split()

### part 2 of the function

    for line in listing:
        if ending in line:
            num = line.split(':')[1]
            warning_label = Label(root, text="\n\nYour password is not safe.\n"
                                             "It is found to have been part of " + num +
                                             " breaches! Change it now!")
            warning_label.pack(pady=5)
            break
    else:
        congratulating_label = Label(root, text="\n\nYour password seems to be safe")
        congratulating_label.pack(pady=5)


def confirm_password_and_compute():
    password = e.get()
    intro.destroy()
    e.destroy()
    confirm_password_button.destroy()
    if password == "" or password.isspace():
        error()
    else:
        compute(password)
    restart_button = Button(root, text="Try another password")
    restart_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: restart_button.invoke())
    suggest_button = Button(root, text="Suggest a safe password. It will automatically be copied to your clipboard!")
    suggest_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

intro = Label(root, text="\n\nThis program checks for pwned passwords!\n"
                         "To check your current password against leaks, enter it here:")
intro.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
e = Entry(root, width=40)
e.pack()
confirm_password_button = Button(root, text="Confirm password", command=confirm_password_and_compute)
confirm_password_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

You have to have the module requests installed for this code to work. In order to do that type "pip install requests" into your terminal.
I have tried the following:

```
import hashlib
import requests
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()


def error():
    error_message = Label(root, text="\n\nThis is not a valid password")
    error_message.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


def compute(password):
    encoded_str = password.encode()
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(encoded_str)
    hashed = hash_obj.hexdigest().upper()
    beginning = hashed[:5]
    ending = hashed[5:].strip()
    response = requests.get("https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/" + beginning)
    output = response.text
    listing = output.split()
    return listing, ending

def the_second_part(password,listing, ending):
    compute(password)
    for line in listing:
        if ending in line:
            num = line.split(':')[1]
            warning_label = Label(root, text="\n\nYour password is not safe.\n"
                                             "It is found to have been part of " + num +
                                             " breaches! Change it now!")
            warning_label.pack(pady=5)
            break
    else:
        congratulating_label = Label(root, text="\n\nYour password seems to be safe")
        congratulating_label.pack(pady=5)


def confirm_password_and_compute():
    password = e.get()
    intro.destroy()
    e.destroy()
    confirm_password_button.destroy()
    if password == "" or password.isspace():
        error()
    else:
        compute(password)
        the_second_part(password, listing, ending)
    restart_button = Button(root, text="Try another password")
    restart_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: restart_button.invoke())
    suggest_button = Button(root, text="Suggest a safe password. It will automatically be copied to your clipboard!")
    suggest_button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)


intro = Label(root, text="\n\nThis program checks for pwned passwords!\n"
                         "To check your current password against leaks, enter it here:")
intro.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
e = Entry(root, width=40)
e.pack()
confirm_password_button = Button(root, text="Confirm password", command=confirm_password_and_compute)
confirm_password_button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

The error I get:
NameError: name 'listing' is not defined

Comment: ```confirm_password_and_compute``` calls the ```the_second_part(password, listing, ending)``` and the ```listing``` was not defined before. Also ```ending``` was not defined either

Comment: but I also call the compute function before it, which should give us the listing ad ending, no?

Comment: ```the_second_part(password,compute(password))``` would solve the problem maybe. ```compute``` returns both ```listing``` and ```ending```

Comment: @Sten You are returning two values from the function `compute()`. But you are not storing those values. It should be `listing, ending = compute(password)` instead of `compute(password)`

Comment: @Sten the problem is that you did not defined anything to the return of this function.

Comment: doesn't seem to be the case for me, unless I'm mistyping something.

Comment: @Sten Try `listing, ending = compute(password)` instead of `compute(password)`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes, it seems to have worked now. Cheers!